# How do camouflage plates know what color to change to?

Tags: internal-consistency, armors, bio-mechanics

How could organic adaptive camouflage be implemented into materials implementable by humans?

I have already developed a general system:

the system is made of small plates that form larger plates. each small plate can change its pigment, but i've encountered issues when trying to explain how the small plates know what color to change.

*if possible, a system that permits "invisibility" while the wearer is moving is preferable, but if not possible, don't stress about it*

the material/plating should be wearable by a human, but can be plating on a wearable exoskeleton so to speak. pseudo-armor?

*I am not looking for general invisibility, please don't answer with anything adjacent to metamaterial cloaking.*

Comment: Hello, it is not recommended to use the [science-based] and [internal-consistency] tags together; which is more important here?

Comment: @AlexP how to replicate active camouflage with the system I've set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is called active camouflage.

There are many researches on that, primarily for military uses. The idea is that the plate changes color pixels on its surface to match what the observer would see if the camouflage object was not there. There is no perfect working prototype yet. However, there are some helpful tricks.

[Active camouflage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_camouflage) - Playing it transparent. This idea mimics the behavior of few animals, mainly octopuses, which match the color and texture of the surrounding terrain, or even the terrain underneath it.

[Yehudi Lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehudi_lights) - Works better when the sky is relatively dark - From dusk till dawn - An array of lights on the body of an airplane shine at the correct brightness to match as much as possible the color of the sky to *an observer below it*.

Yehudi lights are relatively simple to set up, but do not work in all scenarios and at all angles of view. (What if the airplane lights-up to match the sky color, but a far observer sees it with a mountain in the background?)

Active camouflage It is so tricky, because one side must have numerous light receptors while the other must have some LED array which recreates the light, reconstructing the picture the observer would see if the camouflaged vehicle wasn't there. Obviously, the best results are when the camouflaged object is right between the background and the observer. Or else, the observer will see a "wavy" or distorted visual effect. However, in some setups, this would work well. For instance, the [ADAPTIV setup by BAE Systems AB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptiv) uses a system which gathers the infrared signature of the surrounding area and builds a "heat signature image" on the plate facing the enemy side via thousands of hexagonal tiles which radiate the picture of the surrounding as heat. With sufficient technology, you can do the same with light, hence using the octopus method.

You may add a general solution to make it happen in your setting: The vehicle has a wide angle camera on each side. A computer takes the picture and processes it into pixels to light up pixels on the other side of the vehicle. Since a camera requires a small opening, it is possible to install a camera on either side and the rest of the area cover it with dimmable and color-changing LEDs to create a picture.

Answer (score 2):

How does an octopus know what to camouflage into? It's your same question.

Look at the environment, analyze patterns, textures, shadows and so on, and replicate them as best as possible.

If you are on a grass field, turning green should be straightforward. If there are white rocks on red soil, that's what you have to replicate, and so on.

You will need a central system that analyzes the input from a camera observing the surrounding and delivering to each plate the signal on what color to assume.